# Is it possible to get the package name of Activities' caller app when Interprocess Communication?

Tags: android, android-intent, ipc

I have an `Activity` A, which can be called by `Application1` and `Application2`, in my application.

the config of `AcitivityA` in the `Manifest` file is below:

```
<activity
   android :name=".activity.ActivityA"
   android :exported="true"
   android :screenOrientation="portrait"/>
```

How do `Application1` and `Application2` call `ActivityA`:

```
PackageManager packageManager = getPackageManager();
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setClassName(“com.abc.test", “com.abc.test.activity.ActivityA" );
List activities = packageManager.queryIntentActivities(intent, PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY);
if (activities.size() > 0 ) {
   startActivity(intent);
}
```

For security, I want to add a whitelist containing `Application1` and `Application2`'s package name in `ActivityA`, which can be opened only if the package name of the `ActivityA's` caller is in the whitelist.

So is it possible to get the package name of `Activities`' caller app in `ActivityA`?

EDITED:

if impossible without extra data in Intent, Any other idea to keep `Activity A` safety?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as the caller doesn't provide information about itself in an extra, the answer is No.

If you want to secure only specific callers are allowed, use **permissions**.
See

- http://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-tips.html
- http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro.html#sectperm
- http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html

If you own all callers, then I would recommend to sign all these with the same key and use a permission with `protectionLevel` `Signature`.

Another aproach which requires more code is using **services** for the communication.

Quote from first link:

> Using Binder or Messenger is the preferred mechanism for RPC-style IPC in Android. They provide a well-defined interface that enables mutual authentication of the endpoints, if required.

Comment: I don't own all callers, so i can't use permission with protectionLevel Signature. if i use permission with normal, other apps can modify their manifest to use the same permission.

Comment: No, it's a little complicated.

Comment: You'll have to decide how much work your security level is worth. Just be aware that there is no perfect security for any app on android. Using permissions is usually enough. If you have to share highly sensitive data, use services. There is not much in between.

Comment: thanks for your reply, maybe i will use permissions.

Answer (score 1):

Try [getCallingPackage()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#getCallingPackage%28%29) and  [getCallingActivity()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#getCallingActivity%28%29) methods of `Activity`.

Comment: Straight from the docs: `Note: if the calling activity is not expecting a result (that is it did not use the startActivityForResult(Intent, int) form that includes a request code), then the calling package will be null.`

Answer (score 0):

What I do is to pass the calling activity via the intent. eg

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private final static String THIS_ACTIVITY = "MainActivity";
.........

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, ShopAddActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("Caller",THIS_ACTIVITY);
    startActivity(intent);
```

and in another activity (calling same child activity) :-

```
public class ShopListByCursorActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private final static String THIS_ACTIVITY = "ShopListByCursorActivity";

.......

    Intent intent = new Intent(findViewById(R.id.aslbclv01).getContext(), ShopAddActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("Caller", THIS_ACTIVITY + "Update");
    startActivity(intent);
```

And then in the called activity (as one example of detecting the caller)

```
if(getIntent().getStringExtra("Caller").equals("ShopListByCursorActivityUpdate")) {

      DO STUFF HERE
        }
```

Comment: Not sure about the security aspect though, so this might not be secure enough. However, a benefit is that this method can cater for detecting a section within an activity as the caller. In the example above. I appended **Update** to THIS_ACTIVITY to show that the caller is asking for Update mode as opposed to add mode.

Comment: Security is pretty low. I mean, a non-whitelisted caller just has to know a whitelisted callers name, and it can pretend to be that caller easlily. This is nice though if you want to do different things for different callers.

Comment: the appended value could perhaps be a security code of some sort.

Comment: There is no way to keep such a code in secret, unless you want to perform a full SSL-like handshake between the activities.